# What to look for when downgrading from Oracle 10g to 9i?

Tags: oracle, downgrade

I having to downgrade my Oracle instance from 10g (10.1.0.2.0) to 9i (9.2.x.x.x).
Not having planned on ever doing this, I didn't document 10g dependencies.

What are some of the dependencies on 10g that I will have to address?

Is there any type of query that I could perform to detect dependencies?

Of course I'm hoping for a magic bullet, not sifting through volumes of feature additions to compare with 100 klocs of PL/SQL.

By the way, we are not downgrading the database in place, we are migrating from a 10g instance to a separate 9i instance.

Comment: Interesting your downgrading to 9i.  Seems everyone else in the world is upgrading to 10g because 9i support is ending.  Out of curiosity, why are you downgrading?

Comment: The pointy-haired boss says I have to, no logic found here.

Comment: Might wanna check if you have extended support on 9i.  I know the support we have runs out next year.  And it's an extended, extended support plan.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Oracle 10G New Features](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14214/toc.htm) documentation to see what you need to not be using.

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of parameters you could set to put you in 9i compatibility, turn off hash group by's etc.

You could start to make your 10g instance look a lot more like 9i without moving it anywhere. Won't be perfect but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

The biggies (that I know of).  If you have functionality in these areas, take a closer look:

- Regular expressions are new in 10g.
- Nested table collection functions
- Some functionality for hierarchical queries (CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE, NOCYCLE, ...)
- Objects and Collections refinements (new collection functions, modifying the max size of a varray after creation, ...)
- Inter row calculations (SQL MODEL clause).

[@tony-andrews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251069/what-to-look-for-when-downgrading-from-oracle-10g-to-9i#251118): as Tony mentions, there's probably more details in the 10g new features documentation that I'm sure my foggy and uninformed brain has left out.